# How to use `do_shortcode` with Contact Form 7 and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

I made a plugin in wordpress for a form and ajax. When the page successful load the content via ajax, I want to use contact form 7 on the page. I use the `do_shortcode()` tag as explain on contact form 7 faqs but it's fail to display the form. Below are the example that I am doing:

**function.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_test_enqueue_scripts' );

function ajax_test_enqueue_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'season', plugins_url( '/form-submit.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

    wp_localize_script( 'season', 'myAjax', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    ));

}

add_action('wp_ajax_confirmRequest', '_myConfirmHandler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_confirmRequest', '_myConfirmHandler');

function _myConfirmHandler()
{
    if(isset($_POST['vehicle_no']))
    {
        $vehicle_no = $_POST['vehicle_no'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        echo "Your Data: <br>$vehicle_no <br>$email<p />";
        echo do_shortcode('[cfdb-table form="season parking form_copy" filter="your-platno=' . $vehicle_no . '"]');
        echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="6871" title="season parking form_copy"]'); 
    }

    exit;
}
```

**form-submit.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#submit_payment').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var str = $("form[name=season-form]").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: myAjax.ajax_url,
            data: str + '&action=confirmRequest' 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

1. It will just output [contact-form-7 id="6871" title="season parking
   form_copy"]
2. I also use the Contact Form DB but that display the data without a
   problem.
3. I made a research and found this similar problem but still I am unable to solve it. [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/53309/101143)
4. If I write the code directly on the theme page, it will output the form without a problem. May I know how to solve it?

I am still in the processing of learning to develop with WP.

Comment: Hello @Amran is it not worked for you till?? Can I check your files?

Comment: Hi @BlueSuiter, yap, still not working.. How do you want to check the files?

Comment: Please share the link of cfdb plugin, I never used that along the code, I made for you. May we missed something with that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just redo the code again to use back the original like the one you help before but it still output the string.

Comment: Which version of plugin you are using? Also, did you tried to run in `WP_DEDUG` true mode?

Comment: I'm using Version 4.1.2. I already set the debug to true but no error is shown except for `register_widget_control is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_widget_control() instead. in /home/ktm10001/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3246`

Comment: This error is because of some plugin. The version you mentioned is of WordPress?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143140/discussion-between-amran-and-bluesuiter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please `update` your **WordPress**, **Contact Form 7** and **Contact Form DB** to their latest versions. I used the same for while finding for bugs in your code and found it working fine. I hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

H @Amran,

Change the below code:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_confirmRequest', '_myConfirmHandler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_confirmRequest', '_myConfirmHandler');
```

to

```
add_action('wp_ajax_myConfirmHandler', 'myConfirmHandler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myConfirmHandler', 'myConfirmHandler');
```

See if the error still persist.

Change also your code exit() to wp_die()